# How to use ajax to send a data to the php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have updated the ajax, but still passing nothing, I am getting crazy, please some one help me out here. It must be working :(

```
function ajaxFunction(gotid){
    alert (gotid)  

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "profile/php/getorder.php",
       data: {
         dataString: gotid
        },
       success: function(msg){
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
       } 
     });
    }
```

and the PHP

```
 <?php 
   $ordid = $_POST["dataString"];
   $ordid = mysql_real_escape_string($ordid);
   echo $ordid; 

?>
```

why cant see the alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );   ?  Help :(

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery in your pages (like stated in the tags of the question) you'd better make use of it! No need to use XMLHttpRequest. Have a look at this jquery snippet and the jquery docs 
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/path/to/file',
    type: 'default GET (Other values: POST)',
    dataType: 'default: Intelligent Guess (Other values: xml, json, script, or html)',
    data: {param1: 'value1'},
})
.done(function() {
    console.log("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
})
.always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
});
```

Comment: hi, I have modified the function $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "profile/php/getorder.php",
  data: { sndid: gotid}
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });

}   but still no luck, and now I don't have the 2nd alert even

Comment: you should use GET because your php is listening for GET-parameters, not post.

Comment: yes I know that, I have changed the server side too, but no luck

Comment: open firebug console and see if you're getting the console messages. Also I see in your updated question (codeblock) a syntax error. there is a redundant } at the end. The code in my answer is working 100% sure.

Comment: please have look at the updated function, is there any thing wrong with the  way that I am using the function ?

Comment: @ kasper Taeymans  there is nothing in the console, its empty